# Checkbox disabled attribute in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My ViewModel has a property of selected and selectable.  Both are boolean.  I would like my view to have a checkbox that is enabled when selectable is true and disabled when selectable is false.  What is the proper razor syntax to accomplish this ?

I tried the code below on a list of items in a table.  Every row comes back with a disabled checkbox regardless of selectable value.

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected, new { @disabled = !item.Selectable })
```

Comment: Question: What is `item`? I see on your lambda that you have `modelItem => item.Selected`, but is `item` independent from the model itself? Or perhaps you meant to say `modelItem => modelItem.Selected`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It is not easy to achieve this with an `if` condition **inside** the helper method because all the below markups will render a disabled chechbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
<input type="checkbox" disabled="false">
<input type="checkbox" disabled="no">
<input type="checkbox" disabled="enabled">
```

This should work in the razor. Simple If condition and rendering what you want.

```
@if(item.Selected)
{ 
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected, new { @disabled = "disabled"})
}
```

You may consider writing a custom html helper which renders the proper markup for this.

Comment: For HTML5 I write `new { @disabled = "" }` as `<input type="checkbox" disabled />` is valid and used by W3C in their samples.

Answer (score 37):

This won't work because `<input disabled="anything" />` will result in a disabled control. You need to only have a @disabled property when it should be disabled.

Try something like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected, item.Selectable ?  (object)new {} :  (object)new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Note that you might need to cast to `(object)`

Comment: This is a much cleaner option than the selected answer. You do need to cast as object; in my case I had this working: @Html.EditorFor(p => item.Selected, new {htmlAttributes = item.Selectable ? (object)new { } : (object)new { @disabled = "disabled" }})

Comment: You might just be able to go new object() on the left side

Answer (score 7):

The problem is when you have to add more than 1 HTML attribute.
That's a mess:

```
@if(item.Selected)
{ 
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected, new { @data_foo = "bar"})
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected, new { @data_foo = "bar", @disabled = "disabled"})
}
```

What I do to solve this is to use a `IDictionary<string, object>` that is previously loaded:

```
var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>{
    {"data-foo", "bar"}
};
if(!item.Selected)
{
    htmlAttributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

And then I create the checkbox component only once:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected, htmlAttributes)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, my previous answer was wrong.

The input-element will be disabled as soon as it gets the attribute disabled. It doesn't matter if the value is true, false. In HTML you can't set disabled to false.

So you will have to set the disabled attribute only when the condition is valid.

something like:

```
object attributes = null;
if (!item.Selectable)
{
    attributes = new { disabled = "disabled"};
}
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected, attributes)
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation.  Everything comes back as disabled.

Comment: you probably need @ prefixes