# Disabling checkbox in ASP MVC based on bool property?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have an MVC app where the user can register for classes, but I want to DISABLE checkboxes if the user has already registered for a class on the listView.
Trying to disable a checkbox if the user has registered for that item already.
The sessions users registered to are stored in a db.

```
//Controller
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<SessionViewModel> sessionVM;

    using (WSADDbContext context = new WSADDbContext())
    {
        sessionVM = context.Sessions
            .ToArray()
            .Select(x => new SessionViewModel(x))
            .ToList();
    }
    //TODO: Prevent user from registering to the same session
    return View(sessionVM);
}
```

Not quite sure how to wire this property to a user, and check to see if he has this class in his cart.

```
//Model
public bool isRegistered { get; set; }
```

View

```
@for(int i=0; i<Model.Count; i++)
{
    var item = Model[i];
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].SessionId)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].isSelected)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SessionTitle)
        </td>
}
```

I am NEW to MVC, and with some research, I was able to add the property to the view model, but there are multiple users and I need to be able to calculate who registered for what session and disable it on their list of available sessions.
I want my output to look something like below:

[image]

Comment: Disabling a checkbox is likely to have unintended consequences so disabled checkboxes do not submit a value, and if `isSelected` is `true`, then it will be bound as `false` in the POST method. An alternative would be an `if (Model[i].isRegistered)` code block to generate a hidden input if `true` along with a 'fake' checkbox, and your `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` code if `false`

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940746/checkbox-disabled-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940746/checkbox-disabled-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc)