# disabled="disabled" on input type checkbox doesn't work

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:1%;">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <ul class="List">
    @foreach (var req in requests)
    {
     <li>
      <div>
        @if(req.Equals("Test"))
        {
         <label><input type="checkbox" onclick="setRequestor(this)" />@req</label>  
        }
        else
        {
         <label><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />@req</label>   
        }
      </div>
     </li>
    }
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

The Problem is that *disabled="disabled"* is always ignored. If I inspect the Code with Developer Tools I don't see the *disabled* attribute. I see only:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

**EDIT** This is the rendered HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 1%;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="List">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">TEST3</label>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <div>
                     <label><input onclick="setRequestor(this)" type="checkbox" >TEST</label>
                 </div>
             </li>
             <li>
                <div >
                    <label><input type="checkbox">TEST2</label>
                 </div>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2** I tested with the attribute ="checked" and it works. Only "disabled" doesn't work

**EDIT 3 Solution** I resolved the problem with CSS class

Comment: Have you tried just `disabled` without the `="disabled"`? It's a binary attribute, so its mere presence should work.

Comment: Yes I tried without the ="disabled" but doesn't work too

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing more. Please include the rendered HTML.

Comment: I edited my question. Added the rendered HTML

Comment: could you check is something else interact with the check box, something like some js ?

Answer (score 1):

this

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" /
```

with

```
@Html.CheckBox("checkBoxId", new { @disabled = "disabled"})
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you know if this check works:

```
 @if(req.Equals("Test"))
```

To me it seems your code doesn't enter the "else" clause for some reason.

Comment: Even without the "Equal" if I only put `<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />` it is not showing the `disabled` attribute

Comment: Could you please post the rendered result, and a bit more information about what framework you are using. This @ syntax reminds me of PHP.

Comment: its razor (asp-mvc)

Comment: for razor please check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940746/checkbox-disabled-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: But I use HTML inside the `if else` block. I also tried with `checked` and it works. Only `disabled` doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

Try the following instead:

```
@else
    {
     <label><input type="checkbox" disabled/>@req</label>   
    }
```

If you are using a blade template then you need the @ symbol before else.